# TYPO3 FAL Localization not working on production site

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, fal

I'm trying to localize FAL records in inside news records. On my local copy of the page it is working but on production and staging site no more. I can't figure out whats wrong. The AJAX requests seems to send correct data, I compared it with my local request. But on the production and staging sites just gets back:

```
{"data":"","stylesheetFiles":[],"scriptCall":[]}
```

There are no log entries on staging, logging is enabled.

How to figure out what's the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

FAL record localization inside tx_news suffers a bug common to all localization of n:n related models in some configurations: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/57272

If it works on a system but not on another I would look at differences in these TypoScript variables:

```
config.sys_language_mode
config.sys_language_overlay
```